# A central MouseMotionListener in java

Tags: java, swing, mousemotionlistener

I have added a MouseMotionListener in my JFrame to control all mouse motion messages that arrived from all objects in my jframe, but when I move my mouse over a JLayeredPane no message is produced. Please help me to add a central MouseMotionListener in my JFrame to control all messages from all objects in it.

great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use a AWTEventListener to listen for all AWT messages.

Following code shows how to listen for mouse and key events:

```
long eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
    + AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK
    + AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK;

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener()
{
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getID());
    }
}, eventMask);
```

See [Global Event Listeners](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you ... but i am using swing not awt (i have added a swing tag at the end of my question).

Comment: @MicroSystem, Doesn't matter. Swing is built on AWT.  There is no such thing as an AWT MouseEvent and a Swing MouseEvent.. A MouseEvent is a MouseEvent.

Answer (score 3):

Below is code to recursively add a MouseMotionListener to all Components. Be aware that for handling the MouseEvents generated, you need to use SwingUtilities to translate the Point from the specific Component's space to the JFrame's space.

```
public static void installMouseMotionListenerOnAll(Component c, MouseMotionListener mml) {
  c.addMouseMotionListener(mml);
  if (c instanceof Container) {
    for (Component child : ((Container)c).getComponents()) {
      installMouseMotionListenerOnAll(child, mml);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a method in java that see all messages from all component? (i mean that jframe contains all objects and may it would has a central control in all messages).

Comment: What should happen if a subcomponent of the JFrame also listens for  the event, and its listener wants to do the opposite of what the frame's listener wants to do?

Comment: I don't know more about it, but i think a super component can *consume* the massage for a sub component (it can't cause a problem).